# How to change page's html with ajax and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the page in a mobile app. The `window.location.href = 'sth.html'` is works, but my problem is, the time between the change (when I see the white screen under changing).

I know with jQuery mobile it is very simple, but I don't want to use JQM.

Are you know some methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an HTTP GET request to `sth.html` with AJAX and make sure you allow caching on the server.

Only after that request completes redirect.

That would cause the browser to load the page `sth.html` from its cache and not from your server and should effectively eliminate the white screen.